# Understanding state diagram editor

Tags: jointjs

From the blog: http://bl.ocks.org/lgersman/5370827

I want to understand about how connection line between circles are implemented. I tried to go through it but it just went over my head. There's not much documentation about the example I found on blog. I guess other new users like me would be facing the same challenge.

If any one can explain the below sample code, that would be great!

Here's the code I minified for my requirement:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>d3.js selection frame example</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.5/d3.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/app.css" />
        <script>
            window.onload = function ()
            {
                var radius = 40;

                window.states = [
                    {x: 43, y: 67, label: "first", transitions: []},
                    {x: 340, y: 150, label: "second", transitions: []},
                    {x: 200, y: 250, label: "third", transitions: []}
                ];

                window.svg = d3.select('body')
                        .append("svg")
                        .attr("width", "960px")
                        .attr("height", "500px");

                // define arrow markers for graph links
                svg.append('svg:defs').append('svg:marker')
                        .attr('id', 'end-arrow')
                        .attr('viewBox', '0 -5 10 10')
                        .attr('refX', 4)
                        .attr('markerWidth', 8)
                        .attr('markerHeight', 8)
                        .attr('orient', 'auto')
                        .append('svg:path')
                        .attr('d', 'M0,-5L10,0L0,5')
                        .attr('class', 'end-arrow')
                        ;


                // line displayed when dragging new nodes
                var drag_line = svg.append('svg:path')
                        .attr({
                            'class': 'dragline hidden',
                            'd': 'M0,0L0,0'
                        })
                        ;

             **// NEED EXPLANATION FROM HERE**
                var gTransitions = svg.append('g').selectAll("path.transition");
                var gStates = svg.append("g").selectAll("g.state");

                var transitions = function () {
                    return states.reduce(function (initial, state) {
                        return initial.concat(
                                state.transitions.map(function (transition) {
                                    return {source: state, transition: transition};
                                })
                                );
                    }, []);
                };

                var transformTransitionEndpoints = function (d, i) {
                    var endPoints = d.endPoints();

                    var point = [
                        d.type == 'start' ? endPoints[0].x : endPoints[1].x,
                        d.type == 'start' ? endPoints[0].y : endPoints[1].y
                    ];

                    return "translate(" + point + ")";
                }

                var transformTransitionPoints = function (d, i) {
                    return "translate(" + [d.x, d.y] + ")";
                }

                var computeTransitionPath = (function () {
                    var line = d3.svg.line()
                            .x(function (d, i) {
                                return d.x;
                            })
                            .y(function (d, i) {
                                return d.y;
                            })
                            .interpolate("cardinal");

                    return function (d) {

                        var source = d.source,
                                target = d.transition.points.length && d.transition.points[0] || d.transition.target,
                                deltaX = target.x - source.x,
                                deltaY = target.y - source.y,
                                dist = Math.sqrt(deltaX * deltaX + deltaY * deltaY),
                                normX = deltaX / dist,
                                normY = deltaY / dist,
                                sourcePadding = radius + 4, //d.left ? 17 : 12,
                                sourceX = source.x + (sourcePadding * normX),
                                sourceY = source.y + (sourcePadding * normY);

                        source = d.transition.points.length && d.transition.points[ d.transition.points.length - 1] || d.source;
                        target = d.transition.target;
                        deltaX = target.x - source.x;
                        deltaY = target.y - source.y;
                        dist = Math.sqrt(deltaX * deltaX + deltaY * deltaY);
                        normX = deltaX / dist;
                        normY = deltaY / dist;
                        targetPadding = radius + 8;//d.right ? 17 : 12,
                        targetX = target.x - (targetPadding * normX);
                        targetY = target.y - (targetPadding * normY);

                        var points =
                                [{x: sourceX, y: sourceY}].concat(
                                d.transition.points,
                                [{x: targetX, y: targetY}]
                                )
                                ;

                        var l = line(points);

                        return l;
                    };
                })();

                var dragPoint = d3.behavior.drag()
                        .on("drag", function (d, i) {
                            console.log("transitionmidpoint drag");
                            var gTransitionPoint = d3.select(this);

                            gTransitionPoint.attr("transform", function (d, i) {
                                d.x += d3.event.dx;
                                d.y += d3.event.dy;
                                return "translate(" + [d.x, d.y] + ")"
                            });

                            // refresh transition path
                            gTransitions.selectAll("path").attr('d', computeTransitionPath);
                            // refresh transition endpoints
                            gTransitions.selectAll("circle.endpoint").attr({
                                transform: transformTransitionEndpoints
                            });

                            // refresh transition points
                            gTransitions.selectAll("circle.point").attr({
                                transform: transformTransitionPoints
                            });

                            d3.event.sourceEvent.stopPropagation();
                        });

                var renderTransitionMidPoints = function (gTransition) {
                    gTransition.each(function (transition) {
                        var transitionPoints = d3.select(this).selectAll('circle.point').data(transition.transition.points, function (d) {
                            return transition.transition.points.indexOf(d);
                        });

                        transitionPoints.enter().append("circle")
                                .attr({
                                    'class': 'point',
                                    r: 4,
                                    transform: transformTransitionPoints
                                })
                                .call(dragPoint);
                        transitionPoints.exit().remove();
                    });
                };

                var renderTransitionPoints = function (gTransition) {
                    gTransition.each(function (d) {
                        var endPoints = function () {
                            var source = d.source,
                                    target = d.transition.points.length && d.transition.points[0] || d.transition.target,
                                    deltaX = target.x - source.x,
                                    deltaY = target.y - source.y,
                                    dist = Math.sqrt(deltaX * deltaX + deltaY * deltaY),
                                    normX = deltaX / dist,
                                    normY = deltaY / dist,
                                    sourceX = source.x + (radius * normX),
                                    sourceY = source.y + (radius * normY);

                                    source = d.transition.points.length && d.transition.points[ d.transition.points.length - 1] || d.source;
                                    target = d.transition.target;
                                    deltaX = target.x - source.x;
                                    deltaY = target.y - source.y;
                                    dist = Math.sqrt(deltaX * deltaX + deltaY * deltaY);
                                    normX = deltaX / dist;
                                    normY = deltaY / dist;
                                    targetPadding = radius + 8;//d.right ? 17 : 12,
                                    targetX = target.x - (radius * normX);
                                    targetY = target.y - (radius * normY);

                            return [{x: sourceX, y: sourceY}, {x: targetX, y: targetY}];
                        };

                        var transitionEndpoints = d3.select(this).selectAll('circle.endpoint').data([
                            {endPoints: endPoints, type: 'start'},
                            {endPoints: endPoints, type: 'end'}
                        ]);

                        transitionEndpoints.enter().append("circle")
                                .attr({
                                    'class': function (d) {
                                        return 'endpoint ' + d.type;
                                    },
                                    r: 4,
                                    transform: transformTransitionEndpoints
                                })
                                ;
                        transitionEndpoints.exit().remove();
                    });
                };

                var renderTransitions = function () {
                    gTransition = gTransitions.enter().append('g')
                            .attr({
                                'class': 'transition'
                            })

                    gTransition.append('path')
                            .attr({
                                d: computeTransitionPath,
                                class: 'background'
                            })
                            .on({
                                dblclick: function (d, i) {
                                    gTransition = d3.select(d3.event.target.parentElement);
                                    if (d3.event.ctrlKey) {
                                        var p = d3.mouse(this);

                                        gTransition.classed('selected', true);
                                        d.transition.points.push({x: p[0], y: p[1]});

                                        renderTransitionMidPoints(gTransition, d);
                                        gTransition.selectAll('path').attr({
                                            d: computeTransitionPath
                                        });
                                    } else {
                                        var gTransition = d3.select(d3.event.target.parentElement),
                                                transition = gTransition.datum(),
                                                index = transition.source.transitions.indexOf(transition.transition);

                                        transition.source.transitions.splice(index, 1)
                                        gTransition.remove();

                                        d3.event.stopPropagation();
                                    }
                                }
                            });

                    gTransition.append('path')
                            .attr({
                                d: computeTransitionPath,
                                class: 'foreground'
                            });

                    renderTransitionPoints(gTransition);
                    renderTransitionMidPoints(gTransition);

                    gTransitions.exit().remove();
                };

                var renderStates = function () {
                    var gState = gStates.enter()
                            .append("g")
                            .attr({
                                "transform": function (d) {
                                    return "translate(" + [d.x, d.y] + ")";
                                },
                                'class': 'state'
                            })
                            .call(drag);

                    gState.append("circle")
                            .attr({
                                r: radius + 4,
                                class: 'outer'
                            })
                            .on({
                                mousedown: function (d) {
                                    console.log("state circle outer mousedown");
                                    startState = d, endState = undefined;

                                    // reposition drag line
                                    drag_line
                                            .style('marker-end', 'url(#end-arrow)')
                                            .classed('hidden', false)
                                            .attr('d', 'M' + d.x + ',' + d.y + 'L' + d.x + ',' + d.y);

                                    // force element to be an top
                                    this.parentNode.parentNode.appendChild(this.parentNode);
                                    //d3.event.stopPropagation();
                                },
                                mouseover: function () {
                                    svg.select("rect.selection").empty() && d3.select(this).classed("hover", true);
                                },
                                mouseout: function () {
                                    svg.select("rect.selection").empty() && d3.select(this).classed("hover", false);
                                    //$( this).popover( "hide");
                                }
                            });

                    gState.append("circle")
                            .attr({
                                r: radius,
                                class: 'inner'
                            })
                            .on({
                                mouseover: function () {
                                    svg.select("rect.selection").empty() && d3.select(this).classed("hover", true);
                                },
                                mouseout: function () {
                                    svg.select("rect.selection").empty() && d3.select(this).classed("hover", false);
                                },
                            });
                };

                var startState, endState;
                var drag = d3.behavior.drag()
                        .on("drag", function (d, i) {
                            console.log("drag");
                            if (startState) {
                                return;
                            }

                            var selection = d3.selectAll('.selected');

                            // if dragged state is not in current selection
                            // mark it selected and deselect all others
                            if (selection[0].indexOf(this) == -1) {
                                selection.classed("selected", false);
                                selection = d3.select(this);
                                selection.classed("selected", true);
                            }

                            // move states
                            selection.attr("transform", function (d, i) {
                                d.x += d3.event.dx;
                                d.y += d3.event.dy;
                                return "translate(" + [d.x, d.y] + ")"
                            });

                            // move transistion points of each transition 
                            // where transition target is also in selection
                            var selectedStates = d3.selectAll('g.state.selected').data();
                            var affectedTransitions = selectedStates.reduce(function (array, state) {
                                return array.concat(state.transitions);
                            }, [])
                                    .filter(function (transition) {
                                        return selectedStates.indexOf(transition.target) != -1;
                                    });
                            affectedTransitions.forEach(function (transition) {
                                for (var i = transition.points.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                                    var point = transition.points[i];
                                    point.x += d3.event.dx;
                                    point.y += d3.event.dy;
                                }
                            });

                            // reappend dragged element as last 
                            // so that its stays on top 
                            selection.each(function () {
                                this.parentNode.appendChild(this);
                            });

                            // refresh transition path
                            gTransitions.selectAll("path").attr('d', computeTransitionPath);

                            // refresh transition endpoints
                            gTransitions.selectAll("circle.endpoint").attr({
                                transform: transformTransitionEndpoints
                            });
                            // refresh transition points
                            gTransitions.selectAll("circle.point").attr({
                                transform: transformTransitionPoints
                            });

                            d3.event.sourceEvent.stopPropagation();
                        })
                        .on("dragend", function (d) {
                            console.log("dragend");
                            // needed by FF
                            drag_line.classed('hidden', true)
                                    .style('marker-end', '');

                            if (startState && endState) {
                                startState.transitions.push({label: "transition label 1", points: [], target: endState});
                                update();
                            }
                            startState = undefined;
                            d3.event.sourceEvent.stopPropagation();
                        });

                svg.on({
                    mousedown: function () {
                        console.log("mousedown", d3.event.target);
                        if (d3.event.target.tagName == 'svg') {
                            if (!d3.event.ctrlKey) {
                                d3.selectAll('g.selected').classed("selected", false);
                            }
                            var p = d3.mouse(this);
                        }
                    },
                    mousemove: function () {
                        var p = d3.mouse(this);
                            // update drag line
                            drag_line.attr('d', 'M' + startState.x + ',' + startState.y + 'L' + p[0] + ',' + p[1]);
                            var state = d3.select('g.state .inner.hover');
                            endState = (!state.empty() && state.data()[0]) || undefined;
                    },
                    mouseup: function () {
                        console.log("mouseup");
                        // remove temporary selection marker class
                        d3.selectAll('g.state.selection').classed("selection", false);
                    },
                    mouseout: function () 
                    {
                        if (!d3.event.relatedTarget || d3.event.relatedTarget.tagName == 'HTML') {
                            // remove temporary selection marker class
                            d3.selectAll('g.state.selection').classed("selection", false);
                        }
                    }
                });

                update();

                function update() {
                    gStates = gStates.data(states, function (d) {
                        return states.indexOf(d);
                    });
                    renderStates();

                    var _transitions = transitions();
                    gTransitions = gTransitions.data(_transitions, function (d) {
                        return _transitions.indexOf(d);
                    });
                    renderTransitions();
                }
                ;
            };
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

Css file:

```
rect.selection {
    stroke          : gray;
    stroke-dasharray: 2px;
    stroke-opacity  : 0.5;
    fill            : transparent;
}

g.state circle {
    stroke  : gray;            
}

g.state circle.inner {
    fill        : white;
    transition  : fill 0.5s;
    cursor      : move;
}

g.state circle.inner.hover,
g.state circle.outer.hover {
    fill : aliceblue;
}

g.state circle.outer.hover {
    stroke-width    : 1px;
}

g.state circle.outer {
    stroke-width    : 0px;
    stroke-dasharray: 2px;
    stroke-color    : gray;
    fill            : transparent;
    transition      : all 0.5s;
    cursor          : pointer;
}

g.state.selected circle.outer {
    stroke-width    : 1px;
}

g.state text {
    font                : 12px sans-serif;
    font-weight         : bold;
    pointer-events      : none;
}

g.transition path,
path.dragline {
    fill        : none;
    stroke      : gray;
    stroke-width: 1px;
}

g.transition path.foreground {
    marker-end  : url(#end-arrow);
}

g.transition.hover path.background {
    stroke-dasharray: none;
    stroke : aliceblue;
    stroke-opacity  : 1.0;
    transition : all 0.5s;
}

g.transition path.background {
    stroke-dasharray: none;
    stroke-width: 8px;
    stroke : transparent;
}

g.transition.selected path.foreground {
    stroke-dasharray: 2px;
    stroke-color    : gray;
}


g.transition path {
    cursor : default;
}

.end-arrow {
    fill            : gray;
    stroke-width    : 1px;
}

g.transition circle.endpoint {
    display         : none;
    fill            : none;
    cursor          : pointer;
    stroke          : gray;
    stroke-dasharray: 2px;
}

g.transition circle.point {
    display         : none;
    fill            : aliceblue;
    cursor          : move;
    stroke          : gray;
}

g.transition.selected circle.endpoint,
g.transition.selected circle.point {
    display        : inline;
    transition : all 0.5s;
}

g.transition:not( .selected).hover *,
path.dragline {
    display         : inline;

}


g.transition:not( .selected).hover {
    transition      : all 0.5s;
}

path.dragline {
    pointer-events: none;
    stroke-opacity  : 0.5;
    stroke-dasharray: 2px;
}

path.dragline.hidden {
    stroke-width: 0;
}

    /* disable text selection */
svg *::selection {
    background : transparent;
}

svg *::-moz-selection {
    background:transparent;
}

svg *::-webkit-selection {
    background:transparent;
}
```

I understand the basics about d3 such as appending new circle and drag behaviors, but mainly the transitions part used to draw and connect lines to circle is holding me back.

Comment: Is there a specific section you don't understand?

Answer (score 1):

There is quite a lot in there and actually, and looking at it it's not actually using typical `css` `transitions` as you might expect. I'll summarize the interesting parts and expand if you need. The interesting section is the following:

```
var dragPoint = d3.behavior.drag()
.on("drag", function( d, i) {
    console.log( "transitionmidpoint drag");
    var gTransitionPoint = d3.select( this);

    gTransitionPoint.attr( "transform", function( d, i) {
        d.x += d3.event.dx;
        d.y += d3.event.dy;
        return "translate(" + [ d.x,d.y ] + ")"
    });

        // refresh transition path
    gTransitions.selectAll( "path").attr( 'd', computeTransitionPath);
        // refresh transition endpoints
    gTransitions.selectAll( "circle.endpoint").attr({
        transform : transformTransitionEndpoints
    }); 

      // refresh transition points
    gTransitions.selectAll( "circle.point").attr({
        transform : transformTransitionPoints
    });

    d3.event.sourceEvent.stopPropagation();
});
```

This is where all the hard work is taking place. This code basically says, whenever the `drag` event occurs (e.g. you move a circle) execute the code within this function.

You can see this splits into sections:

1. Move the point that was clicked by a `d.x` and `d.y` which is the amount dragged from the previous event. This is done using the `translate` transform.
2. Change the path, this is done by updating the `d` parameter, which is how you specify the shape of an SVG path. The code that calculates the path is within the `comuteTransitionPath` function.
3. Update the circle.endpoint - This is a hidden point on the line
4. Update the circle.point - These are points on the line that control the curve, they are hidden by default.

Comment: The above code you are talking about the line draw or circle drag?

Comment: Especially I would like to understand the line draw between circles and this function `var transitions = function () {
                    return states.reduce(function (initial, state) {
                        return initial.concat(
                                state.transitions.map(function (transition) {
                                    return {source: state, transition: transition};
                                })
                                );
                    }, []);
                };`

Comment: @Jcoder99 both, although I've not gone into the detail of the path generation

Comment: I am really stuck at the above mentioned function in the comment

Comment: In my code  how does this selection is happening?  `svg.append('svg:path')`  and  `selectAll("path.transition")`  svg.path and path.transition are not shapes or tags?

Comment: @JCoder999: Will try and add some more to this answer later. The curve is the spline, and at each bend there's a hidden point